# T-SQL a DAX (PowerPivot)

Tags: powerbi

Estoy tratando de transcribir una consulta T-SQL a lenguaje DAX. La consulta seria: "Select Columna1,Columna2 From Tabla WHERE Columna3>0"

Alguna idea de como quedaria la sintaxis?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [ask], te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Previamente necesitas haber importado los datos mediante Power Query, que traerá la tabla en cuestión a Power BI. Si lo que quieres es un método para obtener una nueva tabla (`TablaDestino`) con un filtro deberás crear una tabla del tipo:

`TablaDestino = FILTER (ALL (Tabla); Tabla[Columna3]>0)`

Si tienes Power BI en inglés, hay una pequeña modificación

`TablaDestino = FILTER (ALL (Tabla), Tabla[Columna3]>0)`

Dónde `Tabla` es el nombre de la tabla importada desde Power Query,